# How to access the correct criteriaID in HTML template django

Tags: python, django

I have a form being generated by some html and I want to use a label which is not part of the actual form data, but related to it.

In the current example there are 3 criteria for the assignment and a dropdown is generated to give a student a level for each criteria and a comment about their work. The criteria description however is causing problems, as I am not sure how to fetch the correct one for each form in the formset.

The context includes a list of all the criteria and so I have tried to use something like

```
criteria.forloop.counter0
```

But of course this does not work. Other than this I have also tried acessing the correct criteriaDescription through the other form inputs like

```
form.criteriaLevelID.criteriaID
```

But this also returns nothing. I'm not sure what else to try here, but it seems like the kind of thing that there should be a simple way to achieve.

The whole form looks like the below for reference

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Criteria</th>
          <th>Criteria Level</th>
          <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for form in formset %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ criteria # problem here }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.criteriaLevelID |as_crispy_field }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.comment |as_crispy_field }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class= "btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save Feedback</button>
</form>
```